# Agetty terminating during login on serial connection

Tags: linux, login, terminal-server, serial

I'm trying to login to a server through the serial port using agetty. When I start agetty and open the serial connection, I see the login prompt but as soon as I enter the username (in my case `root`), agetty gets killed. Not only that, along with agetty, it's parent shell is also being terminated. The following command sequence illustrates this. After starting agetty(the second line), I try to login through the serial port but end up losing the connection as below.

```
ROOT@dir1(~)
(0)#agetty 115200 /dev/ttyS0
Connection to dir1 closed.
```

Any suggestions on why this might be happening? I'm using SLES version 10 and the serial port is connected to a terminal server that is being accessed through a web browser. I'm not sure if rebooting the server with an entry in inittab would make a difference but I'm not inclined towards that as this is a production server and down-times are expensive.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MichaelHampton. That worked for me!
Although I'm still curious why it would not work when I directly invoke agetty through command line. Can you please throw some light on that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *should* have this in `inittab`, and you don't have to reboot. Just `telinit q`.

As for agetty in a shell, it really was not designed to run in the foreground and control some other terminal; while you *could* pass it a tty argument of `-`, this would cause it to print a login prompt in your terminal, rather than on the serial port, which isn't what you want.